# How to count whitespaces as a childnodes?

Tags: html

Whitespace count as empty text element in a DOM.
How can I count these whitespaces?

for example

```
<body>

    <div>

    </div>

    <div>

    </div>

</body>
```

how many whitespaces(childNodes) inside the body element?

how many whitespaces(childNodes) inside each div element?

Comment: Because how can I access an element inside for example a body element if I didnt know how many childnodes inside that body. I dont want to use innerHTML.

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted has 5 whitespaces. I'll explain to you why is that. Firstly I'd like to let it clear that when I refer to whitepace I'm not only talking about the `" "` char. Whitespace may also be `\t`, `\r` or `\n` chars, which represent empty [Text](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-1312295772) Nodes.

With that said, we can talk about how the code you posted is represented in the DOM:

```
body
 |
 x-- #Text = "\n\t"
 |
 x-- div
 |    |
 |    x-- #Text = "\n\t"
 |
 x-- #Text = "\n\t"
 |  
 x-- div
 |    |
 |    x-- #Text = "\n\t"
 |
 x-- #Text = "\n"
```

As you can notice, the `\n` and `\t` are in the same text Node. This is conforming with the **DOM Level 2** says:

> When a document is first made available via the DOM, there is only one Text node for each block of text.

So the break-line that pushes down the `div` is in the same text Node as the tab that pushes it right.
We can go further and add a text to one of the `div`s:

```
<body>

    <div>

    </div>

    <div>
        Hello World!
    </div>

</body>
```

That would be parsed by the browser like:

```
body
 |
 x-- #Text = "\n\t"
 |
 x-- div
 |    |
 |    x-- #Text = "\n\t"
 |
 x-- #Text = "\n\t"
 |  
 x-- div
 |    |
 |    x-- #Text = "\n\t Hello World! \n\t"
 |
 x-- #Text = "\n"
```

The text is grouped with the two whitespaces nodes, because everything is text, thus they become a single block of text. This is the way you should count whitespaces in a document.

But I wouldn't rely on my eyes and try to find or access an element based on counting whitespaces. Instead use some script to loop through the `childNodes` and check for the `nodeType` of the [element](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-1950641247).

**[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Whitespace_in_the_DOM)** you have some useful functions to transversal the DOM without worrying about whitespaces.

Ok, enough of words. Let's see some code. To prove that the HTML you posted has 5 whitespaces, see this working **[example](http://jsfiddle.net/ntv2z/)** that counts all text Nodes in the document.


Hope it helps to clarify something.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to see how many elements are empty? Then I am giving you a jQuery solution instead.

```
bodyChild = $("body :empty").length;
divHcild = $("#divid :empty").length;
```

Using them, you can know what many elements are completely empty inside an element.

---

**Update:**
To get all the child element, you can use something like this

Body:

```
var children = document.getElementByTagName('body').childNodes;
```

Comment: how about counting how many childnodes without doing that just by looking at the code??

Comment: @user1394479, That is how you will be accessing those elements. Using `length` and probably a `for loop`

Comment: My original question .. how about those whitespace??? I read they are childNodes too, I want to know count them.

Comment: headfirst css/html, WHY is that wrong to say whitespaces are childnodes too?